# Installing Dell from zero

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, uefi, ssd

I'm starting with Linux from zero, with no idea. The kind of person that always use Windows in a simple way. So for this I format a Dell notebook, and install Ubuntu. But a lot of things happen in the middle, and I want to redo it, and install at least for the first time in a good way. It's a topic that there is a lot of info out there, but I have so many questions that I'm a little bit overwhelmed.

So, I have 1 TB HDD, and 128 GB SSD. I put to install manually, and put the ssd in a Ex4 in root, and the Hdd in Ex4 but at /home (don't know why, I copy a guy in the internet), and also I put in my ssd a EFI space.

I was reading that this may be not the best thing to do, or that I also need a swap area, or to put my hdd in other place, etc.

Other thing is, that I have a Dell inspiron 7460, I want Ubuntu 18.04, I go with UEFI, or Legacy?(no idea again)

Can someone help me to guide me a little bit? at least what to search or not to.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You already have an installation Live USB which is the first challenge.

Pull out your HDD and leave the SSD as the first drive (swap bays if necessary).

Boot up and press <kbd>F2</kbd> for BIOS menu.

Ensure UEFI is turned on, AHCI is turned on (not IRST) and secure boot is turned off.

Select boot from USB and proceed to exit BIOS.

When Ubuntu starts up choose to install and erase entire disk.

That about covers it.

The HDD makes a nice paper weight until such time as you need to use it for storing videos or on-line backups.

Comment: **NOTE:** You have 8 to 12 GB of ram (confirm if different) so swap is unnecessary for your purposes. If needed for hibernation (not recommended) you can create a swap file later. A swap partition of 12 GB is a waste of SSD space. If prompted you want to create a single partition for everything. These instructions are sparse because you've already erased Windows 10. Personally I would have kept it but shrank it's size to 30 or 40 GB and given the rest to Ubuntu but it's too late for that now.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks you very much. I have 16Gb of ram. So i think, that i do not need swap.

Comment: Yes. My two Dells each have 8 GB and never run out of RAM